# Even after setting up the connect via private endpoint, Azure Data Factory remains accessible over the Internet?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Even after setting up the connect via private endpoint, Azure Data Factory remains accessible over the Internet?

[image]

Private Connections

[image]

Private Zone Entries

[image]

[image]

It is accessible over the Internet

[image]

How to restrict the Data Factory access only within the VNET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , with the current scope it is not possible to restrict the ADF access via  Vnet.
It can be accessed from anywhere but this request is currently in MSFT backlog with many employees requesting the same feature

a similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1034267/azure-data-factory-portal-is-accesible-over-intern.html

Answer (score 1):

The Private Endpoint you have created is only valid for use with Self-Hosted Integration Runtimes and does not apply to the Data Factory Studio portal.

> "Choose whether to connect your self-hosted integration runtime to >Azure Data Factory via public endpoint or private endpoint. This >applies to self-hosted integration runtime running either on premises >or inside customer managed Azure virtual network"

Comment: How do I restrict the access to the Data Factory Studio portal? It should not be allowed to access over the internet.

Comment: I've had a look at this a bit more and I'm confused. Not at your question, it's a very valid question considering it does let you create private endpoints for the portal endpoint. I have managed to replicate your problem. However, in the Network Access tab in the Networking blade it appears you can only lock down the self-hosted IR endpoint. Looks to not be possible to do what you want in the Portal. I shall check Az.DataFactory PowerShell/Bicep and get back to you

Comment: There seems to be a bit of missing functionality here, looks like there is no way to enforce the endpoint for the ADF portal at the moment. @MarkKromerMSFT Is this correct, that it's not possible to enfore the private endpoint for the ADF portal?

Comment: This unfortunately sounds like one to either engage with the product group with if you have a means of contact , I've found the send feedback button in ADF Studio useful for starting a conversation with them. or through a support ticket.