# is it possible to restrict access to azure portal from certain locations?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, azureportal

I am working with an EU based client and we are using Azure environment

Now, since tools like ADF and Databricks are browser based  and can be used to display/download data outside the EU -- we need to find a way to control such access.

Suggestions are welcome.

---

If there are any approaches using VPN/client provided VMs, those are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately , with the current scope it is not possible to restrict the ADF access via Vnet. It can be accessed from anywhere but this request is currently in MSFT backlog with many employees requesting the same feature

I am not sure of ADB though

a similar thread : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1034267/azure-data-factory-portal-is-accesible-over-intern.html

[Even after setting up the connect via private endpoint, Azure Data Factory remains accessible over the Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349831/even-after-setting-up-the-connect-via-private-endpoint-azure-data-factory-remai/74355332#74355332)

Comment: I read about conditional AD access - will that be helpful in restricting the access to azure portal ?